# iframe changing main page jquery or html

Tags: jquery, html

i have a iframe and it is linked to pictures.html and on this page i have links
but when i click the links it changes the ifame page is there anyway i can change the main page using jquery or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `target="_top"` to change the top page's location:

```
<a href="page.html" target="_top">change main page location</a>
```

or `_parent` to change parent page's location

```
<a href="page.html" target="_parent">change parent page location</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need jQuery, you can do this regular javascript.

in your iFrame:

```
<a href="#" onclick='window.parent.location="www.newurl.com"' />
```

Answer (score 0):

you could have the links on pictures.html have onclick events that send the location to the parent window.

```
 $(".link").click(function() {
    window.parent.location = $(this).attr('href');
    return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have the link open in a new window or tab....

```
The HTML to open a new window:
      <a href=”http://sitename.com”  target="_blank">Link text here</a>
```